# Заморозить часть строки в git'е

Tags: git, npm, gitignore

Есть npm'овский packadge.json, один из модулей в котором подключается как git-репозиторий с тегом. Проблема в том, что адрес репозитория должен содержать имя пользователя:

```
"some-module": "git+https://qwertiy@git.smth.com/some-module.git#1.2.3"
                            ^^^^^^^_______________________________________ у каждого своё
                                                                 ^^^^^____ версия меняется
```

Можно ли как-то настроить git, чтобы он при выполнении pull, commit, rebase и других команд игнорировал имя пользователя, но обновлял версию пакета без merge-конфликтов?

Т. е. везде имя должно оставаться без изменений: локально - локальное имя, а в закоммиченном - закоммиченное.

А может быть есть какие-то другие способы, связанные не с git'ом, а с npm'ом?

Comment: Нет, такой возможности нет, однако есть хуки, правда не уверен, что они спасут вас.

Comment: все есть:) просто плохо искали

Comment: @KoVadim вы фактически подтвердили мой комментарий. Про хуки я писал, но не был уверен, что есть специально для таких вещей.

Answer (score 5):

Да, это можно настроить в git. Называется smudge /clean (загрязнить-почистить).  Суть в том, что при добавлении файла или извлечении с репозитория он будет пропускаться через фильтр. Итого, нужно будет два фильтра - один будет подставлять правильного пользователя, второй - заменять его на некого "универсально", которого будем оставлять в коде.

Здесь расписано детально, как это работает https://alexzaytsev.me/2014/10/19/git-filter-to-convert-spaces-to-tabs-and-vice-versa/ - но тут для пробелов.

Вначале в  .gitconfig (или .git\info\attributes) добавить фильтр

```
package.json filter=hide_my_name
```

и добавить собственно сами фильтра в gitconfig

```
[filter "hide_my_name"]
    clean = 'remove-name'
    smudge = 'restore-name'
```

remove-name и restore-name - это две программы (или скрипта), которые на вход получат содержимое файла на стандартный ввод и должны будут сделать замену. clean задача будет запускаться перед git add, а smugle - после checkout.

Написание самых скриптов и как хранить имя для конкретного пользователя - это уже домашняя задача. Но я не исключаю, что эта задача может иметь такое решение:

```
[filter "hide_my_name"]
    clean = 'perl -pe "s!git+https://qwertiy@!git+https://XXXXXXX@!"'
    smudge = 'perl -pe "s!git+https://XXXXXXX@!git+https://qwertiy@!"'
```

Comment: Зачем перл, если можно sed? А вообще, я в винде))

Comment: Потому что я знаю перл. Умеете на sed - делайте sed. Но даже на винде в git bash есть перл:)